# how to bulk update in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I was wondering how I can do a bulk update in laravel 4 rather then looping and updating in chunks?

I know bulk insert is like this:

```
$invoiceitem->insert($items_array);
```

Comment: You may see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27539935/1318946

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use eloquent.

```
Model::whereIn($items_array)->update(array('Foo' => 'Bar'));
```

Comment: Missing an arg: `Model::whereIn("id", $items_array)->update(array('Foo' => 'Bar'))`;

Answer (score 0):

Bulk update is easy by installing a simple package

https://github.com/rajmn/batchquery-package

Update multiple column in a table by a specific conditions also insert multiple row at a time

Comment: Given this question was asked nearly 7 years ago I double it needs an answer now :)