# Laravel Bulk UPDATE

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to update a table containing a slug value with random slugs for each record.

```
$vouchers = Voucher->get(); // assume 10K for example

foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) {
    $q .= "UPDATE vouchers set slug = '" . Str::random(32) . "' WHERE id = " . $voucher->id . ";";
}

DB::statement($q);
```

There are about 2 million records so I need to perform this as a bulk. Doing it as separate records is taking way too long. I can't seem to find a way to bulk run them, say in groups of 10K or something.

Tried a bunch of variations of `->update()` and `DB::statement` but can't seem to get it to go.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/mavinoo/laravel-batch

Answer (score 5):

In case someone land in this page like me, laravel allows a bulk update as:

`$affectedRows = Voucher::where('id', '=', $voucher->id)->update(array('slug' => Str::random(32)));`

See "Updating A Retrieved Model" under http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: This still requires the user to make 2 million DB calls, not a bulk update.

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is `Voucher::whereIn('id', [...])->update([...])`.

Comment: This is called a "bulk update" because it doesn't load the model into memory and e.g. perform model events.

Comment: Unfortunately whereIn()->update() only allows you to perform a single update to multiple models, not multiple updates in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

I have created My Custom function for Multiple Update like `update_batch` in `CodeIgniter`.

Just place this function in any of your model or you can create helper class and place this function in that class:

```
//test data
/*
$multipleData = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
)
*/

/*
 * ----------------------------------
 * update batch 
 * ----------------------------------
 * 
 * multiple update in one query
 *
 * tablename( required | string )
 * multipleData ( required | array of array )
 */
static function updateBatch($tableName = "", $multipleData = array()){

    if( $tableName && !empty($multipleData) ) {

        // column or fields to update
        $updateColumn = array_keys($multipleData[0]);
        $referenceColumn = $updateColumn[0]; //e.g id
        unset($updateColumn[0]);
        $whereIn = "";

        $q = "UPDATE ".$tableName." SET "; 
        foreach ( $updateColumn as $uColumn ) {
            $q .=  $uColumn." = CASE ";

            foreach( $multipleData as $data ) {
                $q .= "WHEN ".$referenceColumn." = ".$data[$referenceColumn]." THEN '".$data[$uColumn]."' ";
            }
            $q .= "ELSE ".$uColumn." END, ";
        }
        foreach( $multipleData as $data ) {
            $whereIn .= "'".$data[$referenceColumn]."', ";
        }
        $q = rtrim($q, ", ")." WHERE ".$referenceColumn." IN (".  rtrim($whereIn, ', ').")";

        // Update  
        return DB::update(DB::raw($q));

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will Produces:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
ELSE `name` END,
`date` = CASE 
WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
ELSE `date` END
WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

Comment: I had to change this line to for it to work, added '' surrounding the $data[$referenceColumn]

   $q .= "WHEN ".$referenceColumn." = '".$data[$referenceColumn]."' THEN '".$data[$uColumn]."' ";

After that, it worked as described :-)

Comment: Note: I also added the following line right before the last $q assignment, to remove the last extra comma from the wereIn list. 

  $whereIn = rtrim($whereIn, ', ');

Comment: i have trimed the ',' . please check properly. looks like you are doing something wrong

Comment: I don't think any of the values are escaped and the query is vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score -1):

Chunking results is the best way to do this kind of stuff without eating all of your RAM and Laravel support chunking results out of the box.

**For example:**

```
  Voucher::chunk(2000, function($vouchers)
  {
    foreach ($vouchers as $voucher)
    {
        //
    }
 });
```

Comment: You only provided the solution for chunking by reading the database. Where is the batch update?

Answer (score -2):

I made a bulk update function to use in my Laravel projects. It may be useful for anyone who wants to use the batch update query in Laravel. Its first parameter is the table name string, second is the key name string based on which you want to update the row or rows and most of the times it will be the 'id' and the third parameter is a data array in the following format:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'col_1_name' => 'col_1_val',
        'col_2_name' => 'col_2_val',
        //...
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'col_1_name' => 'col_1_val',
        'col_2_name' => 'col_2_val',
        //...
    ),
    //...
);
```

The function will return the number of affected rows. Function definition:

```
private function custom_batch_update(string $table_name = '', string $key = '', Array $update_arr = array()) {

    if(!$table_name || !$key || !$update_arr){
        return false;
    }

    $update_keys = array_keys($update_arr[0]);
    $update_keys_count = count($update_keys);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $update_keys_count; $i++) {
        $key_name = $update_keys[$i];
        if($key === $key_name){
            continue;
        }
        $when_{$key_name} = $key_name . ' = CASE';
    }

    $length = count($update_arr);
    $index = 0;
    $query_str = 'UPDATE ' . $table_name . ' SET ';
    $when_str = '';
    $where_str = ' WHERE ' . $key . ' IN(';

    while ($index < $length) {
        $when_str = " WHEN $key = '{$update_arr[$index][$key]}' THEN";
        $where_str .= "'{$update_arr[$index][$key]}',";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $update_keys_count; $i++) {
            $key_name = $update_keys[$i];
            if($key === $key_name){
                continue;
            }
            $when_{$key_name} .= $when_str . " '{$update_arr[$index][$key_name]}'";
        }
        $index++;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $update_keys_count; $i++) {
        $key_name = $update_keys[$i];
        if($key === $key_name){
            continue;
        }
        $when_{$key_name} .= ' ELSE ' . $key_name . ' END, ';
        $query_str .= $when_{$key_name};
    }
    $query_str = rtrim($query_str, ', ');
    $where_str = rtrim($where_str, ',') . ')';
    $query_str .= $where_str;
    $affected = DB::update($query_str);

    return $affected;
}
```

It will produce and execute the query string like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_1_name = CASE 
WHEN id = '1' THEN 'col_1_value' 
WHEN id = '2' THEN 'col_1_value' 
ELSE col_1_name END, 
col_2_name = CASE 
WHEN id = '1' THEN 'col_2_value' 
WHEN id = '2' THEN 'col_2_value' 
ELSE col_2_name END 
WHERE id IN('1','2')
```

Comment: **This is vulnerable to MySQL inject !**